# TypeError: Cannot delete property 'Symbol(@xml.js.parent)' of #<Node>

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this Node class:

```
export const symbols = {
  parent: Symbol('@xml.js.parent'),
};

export class Node {

  [key: string]: any;

  constructor(parent: Node, name: string) {


    Object.defineProperty(this, symbols.parent, {
      value: parent,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: false
    });

  }

}
```

I create a new Node and later try to delete one of the symbol keys:

```
/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/xml.json/dist/index.js:141
                    delete self.currentNode[exports.symbols.parent];
                                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot delete property 'Symbol(@xml.js.parent)' of #<Node>
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/xml.json/dist/index.js:141:61)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:248:13)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at onread (fs.js:2115:12)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:676:17)
```

which is tripped by this line:

```
 delete self.currentNode[exports.symbols.parent];
```

anybody know why I can't delete the property?
Since `writable` is set to true for the symbol props seems like it should work, but idk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need the `configurable` prop set to true

```
    Object.defineProperty(this, symbols.parent, {
      value: parent,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true
    });
```